# Pintar celda en rojo cuando pasen 27 días

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

la cuestión es que necesito pintar una columna en rojo  cuando pasen 27 días de la fecha de inicio 
ejemplo

fechaInicio =  2020-03-01 
fecha Fin 2020-04-01

que le fecha fin se ponga de color rojo cuando se llegue al día 27

```js
function pr(){
let date = new Date()

    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    fechaFin = document.getElementById('fechaFin')
    let now= ""
    if(month < 10){
       now = year+"-0"+month+"-"+day
    }else{
       now= year+"-"+month+"-"+day
    }
    console.log(now);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fechaInicio" value="2020-02-20">
<input type="text" id="fechaFin" value = "2020-03-20">

<button onclick=pr()>Pintar Rojo</button>
```

Obtengo la fecha actual
pero no se como preguntar si va en el día 27 de la fecha del fin

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podes hacer es:

- Con [date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getTime) obtener la cantidad de `milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970 00:00:00 UTC` de ambas fechas
- Restar el tiempo de ambas fechas
- Dividir el resultado en el tiempo que reprensenta "un día" (`1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`)
- El resultado sera la cantidad de dias transcurridos entre ambas fechas. Si ese número es mayor o igual a `27`, entonces lo pintas de rojo.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function pr() {
  let fechaIni = new Date(document.getElementById('fechaInicio').value);
  let fechaFin = new Date(document.getElementById('fechaFin').value);
  let tiempo = fechaFin.getTime() - fechaIni.getTime();
  let dias = tiempo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  console.log(dias);
  document.getElementById('fechaFin').style.backgroundColor = (dias >= 27) ? 'red' : '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fechaInicio" value="2020-02-20">
<input type="text" id="fechaFin" value="2020-03-20">

<button onclick=pr()>Pintar Rojo</button>
```